# how can i change the hint_text of TextInput box which is in .kv file , from .py file

Tags: python, kivy

i want to change the hint_text of textbox which is in .kv on the calling function which is define inside the .py file

I know the label text can be changed like this
  self.root.ids.tm.text = '[color=#FF0000]Time over[/color]'
but same does not work in case of textbox ex
  self.root.ids.some_id.hint_text:"some special text "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Changing from within App class

Use `self.root.ids.text_input_id.hint_text = "Something special"`

## Changing from within root class

Use `self.ids.text_input_id.hint_text = "Something special"`

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<HintTextDemo>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
        hint_text: 'Write here'
    Button:
        text: 'Change hint text'
        on_release: app.change_hint_text() 
""")


class HintTextDemo(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return HintTextDemo()

    def change_hint_text(self):
        self.root.ids.text_input.hint_text = 'Type something here'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: TextInput's Hint Text - Before Change]
[image: TextInput's Hint Text - After Change]